# ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time with node-oracledb

Tags: oracle11g, node-oracledb

We use oracle and `node-oracledb` in our backend and would like to use connection pools to increase the performance:

```
 oracledb.createPool({
            poolAlias:      'default',
            connectString:  connectString,
            user:           user,
            password:       password,
            poolMin:        poolMin,
            poolMax:        poolMax
        }).then(conpool => {
                console.log('Connection Pool created!');
            },
            err => {
                console.log('Error creating pool! Error:');
                throw err;
            });
```

and use connections like this:

```
public async execute (sql: string, data: object, options: object): Promise<any[]> {
    try {
        const con = await this.getConnection();
        try {
            console.log(sql);
            const result = await con.execute(sql, data, { outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT, ...options });

            return result.rows;
        } finally {
            con.release();
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(`database.execute exception: ${ex.message}`);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Now, we are regularly getting the following error:

> ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time

and assume it has to do with the `IDLE_TIME` that is probably not set to `UNLIMITED` for security reasons (which I don't really understand to be honest).

Is there any other way to keep the connections alive? I mean, since nodejs is single threaded, I cannot simply perform dummy queries in regular intervals?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the DBA on this, since the point of the pool is to have resources ready to use.

As a workaround, you could do an explicit [connection.ping()](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionping) after getting the connection and then reconnect if the ping indicates the connection is not usable.  This impacts scalbility since it is an extra 'round-trip' to the database.